# Order of execution for Java static blocks

Tags: java, static

I has 2 classes. Class X is the parent class of Class Y. Both of the class has static block. I am wondering the order of execution for static block.

Why Block 3 execute before Block 2?

**Result I get:**

[image: Result I get]

**Java Code:**

```
class X{
    static String a = "ABC";

    static
    {
        a = a + "123";
        System.out.println("Static Block 1");
    }
    {
        a = "ABC123";
        System.out.println("Static Block 2");
    }
}

class Y extends X{
    static
    {
        a = a + "123ABC";
        System.out.println("Static Block 3");
    }
    {
        System.out.println("Static Block 4");
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Y y = new Y();
    }
}
```

Comment: Block 2 is an instance init block, those run on `new`.

Comment: Blocks "1" and "3" are **static** initializer blocks. Blocks "2" and "4" are **instance** initializer blocks. The static ones are invoked when the **class** is initialized. The instance ones are invoked each time an **instance of the class** is initialized. The former must happen before the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` modifier only applies to the block directly after it. This means that blocks 1 and 3 are `static` blocks, but blocks 2 and 4 are instance blocks that will only be called when an object is instantiated.

Taking that into account, the order of execution can be explained as followed.

- `new Y()` is called from the `main` method, so the classloader attempts to load class `Y`.
- It sees that class `Y` extends class `X`, so it attempts to load it.
- The classloader loads class `X`, and executes its static initializer (block 1).
- The classloader finishes loading class `Y`, and executes its static initializer (block 3).
- An attempt is made to instantiate `Y`, so the underlying initialization of `X` is called first, and executes block 3.
- The initialization of the `Y` instance is finished by executing block 4.

Comment: I have one nitpick.  The class loading and class initialization are separate events.  Class loading happens (typically) when some other class is loaded that refers to the class.  Class initialization happens prior to the first time that the class is used in certain ways by executing code; e.g. before the an instance is created or a static method is called or a static field is accessed.

Comment: So, in this case, the triggering sequence is that `new Y()` in `main` creates an instance of `Y`, and `Y` has `X` as its superclass.  So the class initialization order will be `MainClass` before the `main(...)` call, then `X` followed by `Y` prior to `new Y()`.  (You have the class initialization sequence correct ... but not with respect to the class loading.)

Comment: Having said that, class initialization order is not something that the OP should rely on.  It is difficult to work out what it will be in non-trivial cases.  Indeed, it is possible to create cycles in the initialization dependencies ... and the runtime will pick one possible order over the others ... in an unspecified way.  (Which leads to the "interesting" behavior that one class *may* be able to see / use another's `static` fields *before* they have been initialized.)

Answer (score -1):

Static block-1 Static block-2

Instance block-1

Instance block-2

0-arg constructor

Static block-1

Static block-2 Instance block-1

Instance block-2

0-arg constructor

0-arg method_1_

Instance block-1

Instance block-2

1-arg constructor

1-arg method_2_

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).